# Speed up image processing

Tags: python

I'm working on a project of color detection for vehicles at the moment.

I'm using these conceps to abstract this problem:

1. Remove background by edge detector
2. Find dominant color by Colorthief

When I ran my code, it took about 70s for nearly 130 images.
I think there might be a way to speed up this process.

Can you help me to improve it?
Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from colorthief import ColorThief
import os, os.path
import time

t0 = time.clock()

current_path = "/Color_detection/"
folder = os.path.join(current_path, 'toprocess')
choose_write_folder = os.path.join(current_path, 'processed')
edgeDetector = cv2.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection("model.yml")
count_file = 1

def filterOutSaltPepperNoise(edgeImg):
        # Get rid of salt & pepper noise.
        count = 0
        lastMedian = edgeImg
        median = cv2.medianBlur(edgeImg, 5)
        while not np.array_equal(lastMedian, median):
            # get those pixels that gets zeroed out
            zeroed = np.invert(np.logical_and(median, edgeImg))
            edgeImg[zeroed] = 0

            count = count + 1
            if count > 70:
                break
            lastMedian = median
            median = cv2.medianBlur(edgeImg, 5)

def findSignificantContour(edgeImg):
        image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
            edgeImg,
            cv2.RETR_TREE,
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
        )
        # Find level 1 contours
        level1Meta = []
        for contourIndex, tupl in enumerate(hierarchy[0]):
            # Each array is in format (Next, Prev, First child, Parent)
            # Filter the ones without parent
            if tupl[3] == -1:
                tupl = np.insert(tupl.copy(), 0, [contourIndex])
                level1Meta.append(tupl)

        # From among them, find the contours with large surface area.
        contoursWithArea = []
        for tupl in level1Meta:
            contourIndex = tupl[0]
            contour = contours[contourIndex]
            area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            contoursWithArea.append([contour, area, contourIndex])
            
        contoursWithArea.sort(key=lambda meta: meta[1], reverse=True)
        largestContour = contoursWithArea[0][0]
        return largestContour

def remove_background(im):
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 0)
    blurred_float = blurred.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    edges = edgeDetector.detectEdges(blurred_float) * 255.0
    #cv2.imwrite('edge-raw.jpg', edges)

    edges_8u = np.asarray(edges, np.uint8)
    filterOutSaltPepperNoise(edges_8u)
    #cv2.imwrite('edge.jpg', edges_8u)

    contour = findSignificantContour(edges_8u)
    # Draw the contour on the original image
    contourImg = np.copy(im)
    cv2.drawContours(contourImg, [contour], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA, maxLevel=1)
    #cv2.imwrite('contour.jpg', contourImg)

    mask = np.zeros_like(edges_8u)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, [contour], 255)

    # calculate sure foreground area by dilating the mask
    mapFg = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8), iterations=10)

    # mark inital mask as "probably background"
    # and mapFg as sure foreground
    trimap = np.copy(mask)
    trimap[mask == 0] = cv2.GC_BGD
    trimap[mask == 255] = cv2.GC_PR_BGD
    trimap[mapFg == 255] = cv2.GC_FGD

    # visualize trimap
    trimap_print = np.copy(trimap)
    trimap_print[trimap_print == cv2.GC_PR_BGD] = 128
    trimap_print[trimap_print == cv2.GC_FGD] = 255
    #cv2.imwrite('trimap.png', trimap_print)

    # run grabcut
    bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
    fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
    rect = (0, 0, mask.shape[0] - 1, mask.shape[1] - 1)
    cv2.grabCut(src, trimap, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

    # create mask again
    mask2 = np.where(
        (trimap == cv2.GC_FGD) | (trimap == cv2.GC_PR_FGD),
        255,
        0
        ).astype('uint8')
    #cv2.imwrite('mask2.jpg', mask2)

    contour2 = findSignificantContour(mask2)
    mask3 = np.zeros_like(mask2)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask3, [contour2], 255)

    # blended alpha cut-out
    mask3 = np.repeat(mask3[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
    mask4 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask3, (3, 3), 0)
    alpha = mask4.astype(float) * 1.1  # making blend stronger
    alpha[mask3 > 0] = 255
    alpha[alpha > 255] = 255
    alpha = alpha.astype(float)

    foreground = np.copy(im).astype(float)
    foreground[mask4 == 0] = 0
    background = np.ones_like(foreground, dtype=float) * 255

    #cv2.imwrite('foreground.png', foreground)
    #cv2.imwrite('background.png', background)
    #cv2.imwrite('alpha.png', alpha)

    # Normalize the alpha mask to keep intensity between 0 and 1
    alpha = alpha / 255.0
    # Multiply the foreground with the alpha matte
    foreground = cv2.multiply(alpha, foreground)
    # Multiply the background with ( 1 - alpha )
    background = cv2.multiply(1.0 - alpha, background)
    # Add the masked foreground and background.
    return cv2.add(foreground, background)
    

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread((os.path.join(folder, filename)))
    #src = cv2.imread(filename, 1)
    src = cv2.resize(img, (80, 80), cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    cutout = remove_background(src)

    image_name_to_write = (os.path.join(choose_write_folder,
                                            f'image{count_file}.jpg'))

    # image file is written using cv2.imwrite function
    write_images = cv2.imwrite(image_name_to_write, cutout)
    
    count_file = count_file + 1

    # get the dominant color
    new_image = cv2.imread(image_name_to_write)
    color_thief = ColorThief(image_name_to_write)
    
    dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=5)

    dict_color_value = {"Black": [{"upper": [75, 75, 80], "lower": [0, 0, 0], "label":[0, 0, 0]}],
                        #"Black in light": [{"upper": [115, 115, 120], "lower": [90, 90, 90], "label":[0, 0, 0]}],
                        "White": [{"upper": [255, 255, 255], "lower": [235, 230, 225], "label":[255, 255, 255]}],
                        "Red": [{"upper": [255, 40, 40], "lower": [161, 0, 0], "label":[0, 0, 255]}], 
                        "Brown": [{"upper": [145, 100, 80], "lower": [70, 20, 0], "label":[42, 42, 165]}],
                        "Dark Teal": [{"upper": [60, 145, 145], "lower": [0, 90, 90], "label":[0, 128, 128]}],
                        "Teal": [{"upper": [235, 235, 230], "lower": [125, 185, 185], "label": [155, 215, 215]}],
                        "Dark Gray": [{"upper": [125, 125, 125], "lower": [65, 65, 70], "label":[128, 128, 128]}],
                        "Light Gray": [{"upper": [245, 245, 240], "lower": [235, 230, 225], "label":[128, 128, 128]}],
                        "Gray": [{"upper": [255, 230, 240], "lower": [205, 205, 200], "label":[128, 128, 128]}],
                        "Dark Red": [{"upper": [255, 185, 195], "lower": [185, 115, 125], "label":[0, 0, 255]}],
                        "Red Wine": [{"upper": [255, 125, 135], "lower": [165, 65, 85], "label":[0, 0, 255]}],
                        "Red Maroon": [{"upper": [95, 95, 65], "lower": [45, 45, 35], "label":[0, 0, 255]}],
                        "Green": [{"upper": [95, 255, 105], "lower": [0, 165, 0], "label":[0, 255, 0]}],
                        #"Green": [{"upper": [105, 185, 105], "lower": [65, 125, 55], "label":[0, 255, 0]}],
                        "Dark Green": [{"upper": [95, 155, 85], "lower": [0, 80, 25], "label":[0, 255, 0]}],
                        "Light Green": [{"upper": [255, 245, 235], "lower": [230, 235, 215], "label":[0, 255, 0]}],
                        "Orange": [{"upper": [255, 155, 40], "lower": [220, 80, 0], "label":[0, 165, 255]}],
                        "Light Orange": [{"upper": [245, 245, 210], "lower": [200, 200, 185], "label":[0, 165, 255]}],
                        "Yellow": [{"upper": [255, 255, 100], "lower": [225, 200, 0], "label":[0, 255, 255]}],
                        "Bold Yellow": [{"upper": [95, 95, 70], "lower": [45, 60, 45], "label":[0, 255, 255]}],
                        "Blue": [{"upper": [85, 125, 255], "lower": [0, 95, 185], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Coban Blue": [{"upper": [75, 95, 175], "lower": [0, 25, 55], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Velocity Blue": [{"upper": [215, 225, 225], "lower": [140, 185, 185], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Royal Blue": [{"upper": [25, 80, 145], "lower": [0, 35, 105], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Electric Blue": [{"upper": [55, 255, 255], "lower": [0, 205, 225], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Sky Blue": [{"upper": [155, 225, 255], "lower": [105, 145, 190], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Dark Blue": [{"upper": [25, 25, 255], "lower": [0, 0, 115], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Police Strobe Blue": [{"upper": [55, 195, 255], "lower": [0, 145, 225], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Ocean Blue": [{"upper": [35, 175, 255], "lower": [0, 125, 225], "label":[255, 0, 0]}],
                        "Light Purple": [{"upper": [155, 115, 205], "lower": [105, 55, 155]}],
                        "Purple": [{"upper": [195, 55, 255], "lower": [135, 10, 225]}],
                        "Dark Purple": [{"upper": [135, 35, 155], "lower": [45, 0, 85]}],
                        "Royal Purple": [{"upper": [234, 230, 235], "lower": [225, 225, 226]}],
                        "Pink": [{"upper": [255, 80, 155], "lower": [195, 0, 100]}],
                        "Light Pink": [{"upper": [255, 190, 205], "lower": [225, 65, 125]}],
                        }

    image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    i = 0
    dom_color = ["" for x in range(2)]    
    for color, list_values in dict_color_value.items():
        mask0 = np.zeros(image_hsv.shape[:2])
        
        for values in list_values:
            hsv_upper = np.array(values["upper"])
            hsv_lower = np.array(values["lower"])
            #print(hsv_lower, hsv_upper, image_hsv.shape, mask.shape)
            color_mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

        #print(dominant_color)

        if i < 2:
            if dominant_color[0] <= hsv_upper[0] and dominant_color[0] >= hsv_lower[0] and dominant_color[1] <= hsv_upper[1] and dominant_color[1] >= hsv_lower[1] and dominant_color[2] <= hsv_upper[2] and dominant_color[2] >= hsv_lower[2]:
                dom_color[i] = color
                i = i + 1
        
    print(dominant_color)
    if i == 1:
        print(f"Image {filename} has dominant color is {dom_color[0]}")
    else:
        print(f"Image {filename} has 2 possible dominant colors are {dom_color}")

t1 = time.clock() - t0
print(t1-t0)
```

Comment: How big are your images? It may be helpful to lower the size of the images so they can be processed faster.

Comment: I have resize it to 80 x 80. When I reduced it to 50 x 50, it appeared an error like this in line 97



Exception has occurred: error
OpenCV(3.4.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp:381: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty() in function 'initGMMs'